# Couldn't able to set date max attribute as todays date within html

Tags: javascript, date

I am very new to html codes,I have written a simple html code for 2 dates. I want to set `max attribute` of `date` as todays date. But getting error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined" on line 17`.
I am using chrome Version 32.0.1700.107.
however, it works on JSFiddle.

request for help

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
 function getTodaysDate(){
date = new Date();
day = date.getDate();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
year = date.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day; 

return today;
 }
 document.ss.getElementById('depdate').setAttribute('max', getTodaysDate());
 document.ss.getElementById('arrdate').setAttribute("max", getTodaysDate());

 </script>


 </head>

 <body onload= getTodaysDate()>

 <form name="ss" id="ss"
 <br>
 Departure date   :<input type="date" name="depdate" value="" ,  class="ss-q-date"         dir="auto" id="depdate" aria-label="Departure Date &amp; Time :  "><br>

 Arrival date     :<input type="date" name="arrdate" value="", class="ss-q-date" dir="auto" id="arrdate" aria-label="Arrival Date &amp; Time :  ">
 </br>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket on your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, as the error console reports, the `form` element (as with other elements) has no `getElementById()` method; replace the reference to the `form`, and simply use `document.getElementById()` instead.

```
function getTodaysDate() {
    date = new Date();
    day = date.getDate();
    month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    year = date.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

    return today;
}
document.getElementById('depdate').setAttribute('max', getTodaysDate());
document.getElementById('arrdate').setAttribute("max", getTodaysDate());
//      ^-- removed '.ss'
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Smd59/).

Further, I'd suggest using local variables by declaring them within the scope of the function, to give:

```
var date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth() + 1,
    year = date.getFullYear();
```

Rather than using globals (by omitting the `var`).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Smd59/1/).

Finally, you were doing the same thing twice (padding day and month to two-digits), you should make that a separate function to avoid repeating yourself; and there's no need to create a variable just to return that variable on the next line. So I'd suggest, for example:

```
function zeropad(num) {
    return (num < 10 ? '0' : '') + num;
}

function getTodaysDate() {
    var date = new Date(),
        day = date.getDate(),
        month = date.getMonth() + 1,
        year = date.getFullYear();

    return year + "-" + zeropad(month) + "-" + zeropad(day);
}
document.getElementById('depdate').setAttribute('max', getTodaysDate());
document.getElementById('arrdate').setAttribute("max", getTodaysDate());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Smd59/2/).

Comment: Removed'ss',now getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null" on line 17. checked at J
 fiddle, its working there.

Comment: Do elements with the right `id` exist in your DOM? Have you tried putting the script at the *end* of the document (before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: It works if i put script at the end, before </body>. But is it correct method. I am very new, i don't understand DOM, my full html code is in my question, pl suggest. Additionally i want Arrival date min attribute to be equal to Departure date selection. Pl suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have the following issues:

```
<form name="ss" id="ss"
```

should be :

```
<form name="ss" id="ss">
```

Then this should work :

```
document.ss.getElementById('depdate').setAttribute('max', getTodaysDate());
document.ss.getElementById('arrdate').setAttribute("max", getTodaysDate());
```

Alternatively, you can simply refer directly to the element like @David mentioned:

```
document.getElementById('depdate').setAttribute('max', getTodaysDate());
document.getElementById('arrdate').setAttribute("max", getTodaysDate());
```

Comment: removed 'ss', now giving error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null" on line 17.

Comment: yes its working in jsbin & jsfiddle. but as replied to David, it works when i put script at end(before </body>. but giving error when it is head.

Comment: @user3522349: The only reason i can come up is that the function gets executed even before all the elements in DOM are loaded. This explains why it works when its put at bottom of html page. Are you open to using a small jquery snippet?

Comment: yes, pl suggest. Adding one more requirement. I want Arrival date min attribute to be equal to Departure date selection. Pl suggest

Comment: please suggest jquery snippet.